# Legendre transform of a convex downward function

Tags: analysis, legendre-transformation

I have the following function:
$$\lim _{t \rightarrow \infty}-\frac{1}{t} \log \left\langle e^{-\lambda W(t)}\right\rangle=e(\lambda),$$
which is convex downward, where $\langle\exp [-\lambda W(t)]\rangle$ is the generating function of the random variable $W(t)$. We also know that the function has the following property:
$$e(\lambda)=e(1-\lambda).$$
In the article the authors said that the Legendre transform $\hat{e}(w)$ is convex upward, $\hat{e}(w) \geqslant 0$ and
$$\hat{e}(w)=\max _{\lambda}\{e(\lambda)-\lambda w\}.$$
Why these three statements are true?